# remove HTML and show bullet instead of li tag in Android

Tags: android, html

I want to `remove HTML and show bullet instead of <li> in Android`

method to remove html :

```
public static String removeHTML(String value){
    value = value.replace("<ul style=\"list-style-type: disc;\">" , "<ul>");
    value = value.replace("<ul>" , "");
    value = value.replace("</ul>" , "");
    value = value.replace("<li>" , " &#8226 "); // Bullet
    value = value.replace("</li>" , "");
    value = value.replace("<p>" , "");
    value = value.replace("</p>" , "<br />");
    value = value.replace("<br />" , " \n ");
    return Html.fromHtml(value).toString();
}
```

content is :

```
title goes here
    <ul style=\"list-style-type: disc;\">
        <li>line one</li>
        <li>line two</li>
        <li>line three</li>
        <li>line four</li>
     </ul>
```

but when i print system logs is shows :

```
title goes here
    •
line one
    •
line two
    •
line three
    •
line four
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your string is having `\n` character before and after bullets. remove all `\n` .

Comment: so i replaced `\n` with `""` but nothing chnged

Comment: have you check if it is replaced or not please debug and check

Comment: I Have No Idea, I just put Logs Inside Method And Nothing changed, It's Done